# AVSpeechUtterance with volume zero can still be heard

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I'm creating an AVSpeechUtterance and setting the volume to zero. However with some voices (but not all) the utterance can still be heard:

```
let utterance = AVSpeechUtteranceSR(string: text)
utterance.volume = 0
aVSpeechSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

For the voice called Aaron, nothing is heard. For the voice called Eddy, it can be faintly heard.

Any ideas for how to make it completely silent?

The use-case is for memorizing. Sometimes the voice should be heard, and other times a gap (silence) should be heard for the same amount of time that the voice would take to speak.

This is iOS 16.2 and 16.3.1, on a couple of devices. Not sure how widespread the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so no answers to this, so I created a workaround.

As it's playing silently, it doesn't matter which voice is used. I set:

```
utterance.voice = nil
```

so that it uses the default voice. The default voice seems to handle a zero volume OK.